# Is there a way to nest CSS selectors?

Tags: html, css, dom

imagine a html code which I cannot change. something like:

```
    <div class="a">
        <div class="aa">
            <div class="aa1">
    
            </div>
            <div class="aa1">
    
            </div>
            <div class="aa1">
    
            </div>
            <div class="aa1">
    
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="b">
            <div class="bb">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>...
    
    </div>
```

so what I want to change is in 'aa1' s and each one should have different styling.

so in css I could write

```
    .a .aa .aa1:first-child{
        styling1:;
    }
     .a .aa .aa1:nth-child(2){
        styling2:;
    }
     .a .aa .aa1:nth-child(3){
        styling3:;
    }
     .a .aa .aa1:nth-child(4){
        styling4:;
    }
     .a .aa .aa1:nth-child(5){
        styling5:;
    }
```

but there is lot of those 'aa1' parts. Is there a way to simplify this where I only have to specify nth-child(x) for each element?

something like:

```
    .a .aa .aa1
    {
        :first-child{
            styling1:;
        }
        :nth-child(2){
            styling2:;
        }
        :nth-child(3){
            styling3:;
        }
        :nth-child(4){
            styling4:;
        }
        :nth-child(5){
            styling5:;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current CSS (2.1) version, nesting selectors isn't possible.

You'll have to use something called a [CSS preprocessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_preprocessor) which does several things, including allowing nested selectors.

I'd recommend [SASS (SCSS)](https://sass-lang.com/), and another out there is [LESS](https://lesscss.org/). You'll need some extra things setup on your PC/Mac for automatically converting preprocessor files to regular CSS files - plenty of other questions and research points on that out there.

If you use SCSS, you can check out what its like on [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) so you can see what the nested selectors will look like compiled.